# MP4 in background(MainWindow) qt6.3

Tags: qt, c++17, qt-creator, qt6

I would like to know if there is any class that I can work with that accepts mp4, because the multimedia class is not active in qt6.3.
I'm trying to load mp4 files in the background, but I didn't find classes in qt(6.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [QMediaPlayer](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qmediaplayer.html#details) for this.

```
player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/lpapp/Music/song.mp4"));
player->play();
```

For video rendering, you can even use the [QVideoWidget](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qvideowidget.html#details) class:

```
videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
videoWidget->show();
```